# Is this use of an inverse function correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I am trying to make sense of the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem and it's proof. It was a theorem that was stated without proof in a real analysis book but I can't resist the urge to ask how to prove it. The theorem is stated in the first section on basic set theory (Volume 1 Book found here; https://www.jirka.org/ra/).

I found a YouTube video that has an interesting and seemingly intuitive approach to the proof by relating it to Hilbert's hotel however, I noticed he uses the inverse of g which is supposed to be an injection (timestamp of the video: https://youtu.be/IkoKttTDuxE?t=453). From the theorems covered thus far, only bijections have inverse functions. According to Wikipedia, there are left and right inverses. Is this a left or right inverse, how so? Or is this method of proving it not rigorously sound? He also points to the textbook Elements of Set Theory by Herbert Enderton who does use the same inverse on page 162 so I assume I am missing some prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: An injection has an inverse if you restrict the codomain to its range, which seems to be what the video is using. (If you want, you can also understand it as a left inverse, which all injections have.)

Comment: A similar proof is also written down in Wikipedia: https://w.wiki/9Uvu